# Get TextArea input on HTML-Page with ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, html, jtemplates

Using jTemplates I have a HTML-Page in my asp.net 4.0 project. On this HTML-Page I have a text area and a submit button. How could I get the entered value into my asp.net application when the user clicks the Submit-Button?

Comment: Can you post some of your code to work with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in your AJAX request:

```
jQuery('#form_element_id').submit(function(eve){
    eve.preventDefault();
    var updateval = jQuery("#textare_element").val();



});
```